# NameError: name 'pigLatin' is not defined

Tags: python

My code is this:

```
def vowelIndex(wd) :

    def getInitialCs(wd) :
        return wd[:vowelIndex(wd)]

    def getTheRest(wd) :
        return wd[vowelIndex(wd):]

    def pigLatin(wd) :
         if len(wd) == 0: return ''
         elif wd[0] in 'aeiou' :
              return wd + 'way'
         else :
              return getTheRest(wd) + getInitialCs(wd) + 'ay'
```

and when I type `PigLatin('yellow')` This error occured:

---

```
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-128-e025299840a1> in <module>()
    ----> 1 pigLatin('yellow')

NameError: name 'pigLatin' is not defined
```

I want this result:

```
pigLatin('yellow')

'ellowyay'
```

I don't know what`s wrong, please help me

Comment: Why are your 3 functions defined *inside* the `vowelIndex` function? It sounds like you meant to define them in the global scope.

Comment: It looks, as if vowelIndex was intended to be a class, where the constructor receives the wd argument, which can then be used by all subsequent methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `vowelIndex` properly, and not put the other functions inside it (fix the indentation).

```
def vowelIndex(wd):
    return 1          #<-- need a proper algorithm

def getInitialCs(wd):
    return wd[:vowelIndex(wd)]


def getTheRest(wd):
    return wd[vowelIndex(wd):]


def pigLatin(wd):
    if len(wd) == 0:
        return ''
    elif wd[0] in 'aeiou':
        return wd + 'way'
    else:
        return getTheRest(wd) + getInitialCs(wd) + 'ay'

print(pigLatin('yellow'))
```

#### output:

```
ellowyay
```

Comment: I add a return 1 below at def vowelIndex(wd), but same error occured.

Comment: You must fix your indentation. The code I posted works for the example provided - for more functionality, you need to code a proper algorithm in `vowelIndex`, as indicated.